# Are there any scenarios where C4172 Visual C++ warning should not be considered an error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

There's [C4172](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0ws2xs1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Visual C++ warning for cases when a function returns an address of a local or temporary or a reference to a local variable.

Something like this:

```
int& fun()
{
    int var;
    return var; //C4172
}
```

Now looks like it is a good idea to use `#pragma warning` to make Visual C++ treat C4172 as error and break compilation.

Are there any sane scenarios where C4172 is not actually an error?

Comment: So, you want to know if it is okay to treat it permanently as an error - meaning: why was it defined as a warning to start with?  Great question.

Comment: Most likely no, and the compiler is right to provide it as an diagnostic and not as compilation error because it is undefined behavior to return reference to local and not an language syntax error. Why is it no defined as language syntax error? Because it is not an syntax error.

Comment: @jim mcnamara: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @Alok If it’s UB, the compiler is well within its right to treat it as an error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It is, but it does not have to. Question asks why it is not an error. Answer is because it is not an language syntax error as per the standard.

Comment: @Alok But that isn’t the question. (Furthermore, your repeated mention of “syntax” is a red herring, there are other classes of errors that *must* be diagnosed.)

Comment: The language specification allows such programs to compile, and as such the compiler just wants to follow that specification. Maybe it has some special flags where you can change that behaviour, but per default it should not reject valid code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I am just saying the standard does not mandate the compiler to flag this as an compilation error because it merely says that the behavior from such a code is not defined, which is not essentially same as it is not valid to write this code.

Comment: @Alok But, again, that wasn’t the question at all. The question was whether it makes sense *from a user perspective* to always treat this warning as an error, regardless of whether the standard allows the code. That’s completely different.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - the language definition allows **all** erroneous programs to compile; the **only** time a compiler is prohibited from compiling a program is when it contains a `#error` directive. Many errors require **a diagnostic**; if the compiler issues a diagnostic, it is then free to do pretty much anything the compiler writer thought was appropriate.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Jim's comment under the Q and OPs reply in affirmation disagrees with your comment? or atleast it made me think otherwise.

Comment: @PeteBecker: does that mean cwg issue #745 is resolved?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - nope. I was thinking C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why anyone would ever want to do this:

```
int * stackTester()
{
    int dummy;
    return &dummy;
}

bool stackGoesUp()
{
    int dummy;
    return stackTester() > &dummy;
}
```

But generally speaking, you should treat the warning like an error.

Comment: A slightly more sane example: finding out how big a minimal stack frame is (= size of return address?)

Comment: If I understand the C standard, comparing pointers with >, <, >= and <= results undefined behavior if those pointers do not point into the same aggregate object (struct/union) or to elements of the same array (including the non-existent element after the last one). I think C++ is the same here.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: True, *but* `std::less<T>` is defined for pointers, even if they don't point to elements of the same array.

Answer (score 6):

It is a level 1 warning, very hard to ignore.  But the compiler is following language standards here, invoking UB is not forbidden.  And it is a very common bug that too often does come to a good end.  The pointed-to stack location stays stable as long as you don't make any function calls.

The best way to deal with this is to always turn warnings into errors.  Compile with /WX, "Treat warnings as errors" setting in the IDE.  If you then intentionally want to suppress a warning then #pragma warning makes it clear to everybody that something fishy is going on that was thought about and not an accident.

Answer (score 0):

Unused code

```
class base
{
   virtual blah& makeBlah() 
}

class red : public base
{
    blah& makeBlah() { return blah(); } // there are no red blahs, never called
}

class blue : public base
{
    blah& makeBlah() { actual code to make a blah }
}
```